# internet explorer 6 box model

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I am working on a website and i faced a problem with internet explorer box model (padding & margin) so I tried to fix it, in internet explorer 7 i fixed it by using a appropriate doctype but it doesn't seem to work on internet explorer 6, is there any way to fix the internet explorer 6 box model ? any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to provide more info about the specific problem you're facing.

Comment: Do you have xml declaration at the beginning of the page?

<?xml version="1.0"?> may trigger IE6 quirks mode.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use half the margin within a CSS-Hack for the Internet Explorer lt7.

Note it like this:

```
html * selector { margin: foo(half size of elements margin working on other browsers);}
```

I call it the double-margin-float-bug. Here's a [Reference](http://www.cssnewbie.com/double-margin-float-bug/)

Answer (score 1):

In general, I simply try to avoid using width + padding / border.

If you can't, a simple way is using divs: a "wrapper" with width & margin (same with both box models), and another inside with border-width and padding.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact code and issue, the best suggestion I can offer is to take a look [here](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html) for a list of solutions to known explorer problems.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not be useful for you depending on your requirement specifications on this application, I would recommend not supporting IE6 at all. The box model is just one minor problem with it - if you start considering the security flaws of the browser, you have bigger problems with IE6 than a border in the wrong place...

Instead, I recommend implementing something like [IE6 Update](http://www.ie6update.com/), to try and persuade your users to upgrade their browsers.

Comment: Not supporting IE6 isn't an option in a lot of cases. There are still a lot of people that work for big corps that are locked down. And grandma, if grandma doesn't have technical help from someone.

Comment: I konw. That's why i started my answer with "Although this might not be useful for you depending on your requirement specifications"... However, when it is possible, it is often much better both for developers and users if an upgrade can be performed.